# Can I choose photo quality when uploading to Facebook with php Grpah api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a question about photo quality on FB while you are uploading it with graph.

I have upload code, everything is ok:

```
$args = array();
$args["message"] = 'Test Caption';
$args['image'] = '@' . realpath($new_name);
$data = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $args);
```

This works, it uploads. But, image on my server is high quality, but when posted to FB, it loses quality...
Image type is PNG.

Any help?

Comment: Facebook lower the quality of all images uploaded (presumably to save bandwidth). It doesn't matter who API you use to upload them. As far as I know there is no way around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All uploaded images are compressed, stripped of meta / exif, converted to jpeg and resized by Facebook.

Comment: Ok. Didn't think I will be able to influence quality, but needed to see if there was a solution :)
Tnx